# MS Access - Aggregate functions and max

Tags: ms-access

I have this query, where I am trying to get max age of a retail store seller(There's multiple towns), and show multiple if there's multiple people with the same (max)age. I am using Microsoft Access 2010. Here is the query:

```
SELECT Linnad.Linn, Myyjad.Nimi, Max(Myyjad.Vanus) As Vanus
FROM Linnad INNER JOIN Myyjad ON Linnad.LinnID = Myyjad.LinnID
GROUP BY Linnad.Linn, Myyjad.Nimi
ORDER BY Linnad.Linn;
```

The problem is, it seems to ignore the MAX, and just shows all of the values, and I can't remove the group by Myyjad.Nimi, because it gives me an error that aggregate function not included for Myyjad.Nimi.

And the output should be:
Town - Name - Max(Age)

Also, Linn = Town, Nimi = Name and the Vanus = Age.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what you are trying to do, if you translated the table and column names to English.

Comment: Tried that, I'll copy one comment: What I am trying to achieve, is to get the max age of the sellers, and their names, if there's multiple people with the same max age, display them. But the LinnID(TownID) separates them, in to different cities, yet still there's few sellers with the same (max)age. Hope it's more clear now, sorry for confusing. And yeah, I am sorry about being kind of unclear about what I need, but I got it and thanks to all! :)

Comment: What I mean, is that is very hard to read you SQL statement without knowing your language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what your looking for:

```
SELECT L.Linn, M.Nimi, M.Vanus
FROM Linnad As L,
(
SELECT M2.LinnID, M2.Nimi, M2.Vanus
FROM Myyjad As M2
WHERE M2.Vanus = (SELECT Max(Z.Vanus) FROM Myyjad As Z WHERE Z.LinnID = M2.LinnID)
) As M
WHERE M.LinnID = L.LinnID
```

This performs a sub-select to get a list of the Linn ID's with all Nimi's showing the maximum Vanus, then we link this sub-select back to the Linnad table via the LinnID.

Comment: : ) Phew, I know access can sometimes be funny about using sub-selects as named tables, glad to help though

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Linnad.Linn, Myyjad.Nimi, Myyjad.Vanus
FROM Linnad INNER JOIN Myyjad ON Linnad.LinnID = Myyjad.LinnID
WHERE DateValue(Myyjad.Vanus) 
      = (SELECT Max(DateValue(Myyjad.Vanus)) FROM Myyjad) 
ORDER BY Linnad.Linn
```

Top N per group:

```
SELECT Linnad.Linn,  Myyjad.Nimi, Myyjad.Vanus
FROM FROM Linnad INNER JOIN Myyjad ON Linnad.LinnID = Myyjad.LinnID
WHERE Myyjad.ID In (
    SELECT Top 1 m.ID 
    FROM Myyjad m  
    WHERE m.LinnID=Linnad.ID 
    ORDER BY m.Vanus Desc, m.ID)
```

Comment: I suspect you may also have a time element. I will add DateValue.

Comment: I need to display the max age of the retail sellers for each town, and there isn't a datevalue, since the townID is just a relation between 2 tables. And the age is just an integer, only the person's age (like 68).

Comment: I think you want top 1 per group. I have added an order by id, so you will only get one record returned of you have more than one person with the same age.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve, is to get the max age of the sellers, and their names, if there's multiple people with the same max age, display them. But the LinnID(TownID) separates them, in to different cities, yet still there's few sellers with the same (max)age. Hope it's more clear now, sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by Linn (town) and Nimi (name) tells the db engine to give you one row for each combination of town and name, and show you the maximum Vanus (age) for each of those combinations.  And logically, that's not what you want.  You want the name of each person whose age is the same as the maximum age in that town.

First verify you can retrieve the max age for each LinnID.

```
SELECT
    LinnID,
    Max(Vanus) As MaxOfVanus
FROM
    Myyjad
GROUP BY LinnID;
```

If that works, you can save it as "qryTownAge", then use it in another query where you join it (on LinnID) with Linnad.  That will allow you to retrieve the matching Linn.

```
SELECT l.LinnID, l.Linn, q.MaxOfVanus
FROM
    Linnad AS l
    INNER JOIN qryTownAge AS q
    ON l.LinnID = q.LinnID
ORDER BY l.Linn;
```

If that works, save it as qryTownAge2.  Then try this query.

```
SELECT q.Linn, q.MaxOfVanus, m.Nimi
FROM
    qryTownAge2 AS q
    INNER JOIN Myyjad AS m
    ON (
        m.LinnID = q.LinnID
        AND m.Vanus = q.MaxOfVanus
        )
ORDER BY q.Linn;
```

If that all works, you could create a single query which does it all.  However, doing it step by step should help us pinpoint errors.